# spark-sql -e execution cannot have too many count clauses

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I used spark-sql -e to execute below sql. Spark returns an excetpion:

```
ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: 
org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: 
agg_doAggregateWithKeys(): Operand stack inconsistent at offset 778: 
Previous size 1, now 0/* 001 */ public Object generate(Object[] references)
```

Following the source code of GeneratedIterator

But when I execute the same query from a thrifserver client or hive -e command, everything is fine.

Any idea of the root cause??

```
select 
      to_date(action_time) as value_date,
      platform,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='home' then device_num else null end)) as ea_home_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='search' then device_num else null end)) as ea_search_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='searchResult' then device_num else null end)) as ea_searchResult_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='searchResult' and branch='search' then device_num else null end)) as ea_searchResult_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='searchResult' then device_num else null end)) as ea_search_detail_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='search' then device_num else null end)) as ea_search_detail_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='topCategory' then device_num else null end)) as ea_topCategory_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='secCategory' then device_num else null end)) as ea_secCategory_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='secCategory' and branch='category' then device_num else null end)) as ea_secCategory_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='secCategory' then device_num else null end)) as ea_category_detail_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='category' then device_num else null end)) as ea_category_detail_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='H5Page' then device_num else null end)) as ea_H5Page_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='H5Page' then device_num else null end)) as ea_H5Page_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='H5Page' then device_num else null end)) as ea_H5Page_detail_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='h5' then device_num else null end)) as ea_H5Page_detail_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='home' then device_num else null end)) as ea_detail_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='home' then device_num else null end)) as ea_detail_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='salesList' then device_num else null end)) as ea_salesList_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='salesList' then device_num else null end)) as ea_salesList_detail_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='sales' then device_num else null end)) as ea_salesList_detail_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='salesList' then device_num else null end)) as ea_salesList_addToCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='shoppingCart' then device_num else null end)) as ea_shoppingCart_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='orderConfirming' then device_num else null end)) as ea_orderConfirming_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='submitOrder' then device_num else null end)) as ea_submitOrder_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='cashier' then device_num else null end)) as ea_cashier_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='payment' then device_num else null end)) as ea_payment_uv,
      count(distinct( case when action_name='paid' then device_num else null end)) as ea_paid_uv,
      count( case when action_name='home' then 1 else null end) as ea_home_pv,
      count( case when action_name='search' then 1 else null end) as ea_search_pv,
      count( case when action_name='searchResult' then 1 else null end) as ea_searchResult_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='searchResult' and branch='search' then 1 else null end) as ea_searchResult_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='searchResult' then 1 else null end) as ea_search_detail_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='search' then 1 else null end) as ea_search_detail_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='topCategory' then 1 else null end) as ea_topCategory_pv,
      count( case when action_name='secCategory' then 1 else null end) as ea_secCategory_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='secCategory' and branch='category' then 1 else null end) as ea_secCategory_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='secCategory' then 1 else null end) as ea_category_detail_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='category' then 1 else null end) as ea_category_detail_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='H5Page' then 1 else null end) as ea_H5Page_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='H5Page' then 1 else null end) as ea_H5Page_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='H5Page' then 1 else null end) as ea_H5Page_detail_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='h5' then 1 else null end) as ea_H5Page_detail_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='home' then 1 else null end) as ea_detail_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='home' then 1 else null end) as ea_detail_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='salesList' then 1 else null end) as ea_salesList_pv,
      count( case when action_name='detail' and pre_name='salesList' then 1 else null end) as ea_salesList_detail_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='detail' and branch='sales' then 1 else null end) as ea_salesList_detail_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='addToCart' and pre_name='salesList' then 1 else null end) as ea_salesList_addToCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='shoppingCart' then 1 else null end) as ea_shoppingCart_pv,
      count( case when action_name='orderConfirming' then 1 else null end ) as ea_orderConfirming_pv,
      count( case when action_name='submitOrder' then 1 else null end) as ea_submitOrder_pv,
      count( case when action_name='cashier' then 1 else null end) as ea_cashier_pv,
      count( case when action_name='payment' then 1 else null end) as ea_payment_pv,
      count( case when action_name='paid' then 1 else null end) as ea_paid_pv
  from 
      l2_ux_t_pv
  where 
      to_date(insert_time)>='2016-12-20'
  group by 
      to_date(action_time),
      platform
```

Comment: In addition, when I remove some lines of the count clause, it just ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Janino compiler which was fixed in Spark v2.1+ accordingly to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15467

See also:

- https://github.com/janino-compiler/janino/issues/1
- https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14127